# Does opening a file in append mode to write in c++ allocates memory for whole file?

Tags: c++, file, operating-system, append

Does opening a file in append mode to write in `c++` allocates memory for the whole file?

Say I have a file, then I opened in append mode and after the final append the file is `34 GB`. Now if the file write operation is frequent and done by different tasks, which opens the file every time to append some data to it. just before the final write(when the size of the file is about `30 GB`) will the OS allocate `30 GB` for opening a file?

Comment: You need to study a book with basic contents about files a I/O. You will find many interesting things, specially that your idea does not make sense.

Comment: You should go through tutorials explaining how I/O is done.Your question is putting a 'question' on memory management component of operating system.Check https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/13_IOSystems.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. Opening the file, in any mode, does not allocate memory for the whole file. You may have that confused with memory-mapping a file, which can and usually does.